# Is it correct to say "of all the things money can't buy, law isn't one"?

Tags: grammaticality, meaning-in-context

Is "Of all the things money can't buy, law isn't one" grammatically correct?

Comment: Sadly, it is correct.  (Though you have to think about it a bit to get the meaning.)

Comment: Makes no sense to me. "Of all the things" expressly means that law is one of those things. But then you say that it isn't. Which one is it, now. You can't have it both ways.

Comment: @RegDwigнt - "Of all the things" means that this collection to my right is the complete set of things that money can't buy.  Why is it wrong to say that "law" isn't in that collection?

Comment: @HotLicks because by saying "of all the things" you have expressly included the law in that collection. And now you're trying to exclude it. You are contradicting yourself. The fixed phrase "of all the things/people" is used to highlight the fact that you have many options, and you pick one of those options, but your choice is poor or otherwise peculiar. You can say "of all the cars you could buy, you went with Dodge?" But you can't say "of all the cars you could buy, bicycle isn't". That just makes no sense at all.

Comment: @RegDwigнt - How do you know what's included in the set?  Yeah, it's not using the phrase in the usual idiomatic fashion, but that's just part of the (intentional) garden pathiness of it all.

Comment: I know what's included in the set because you yourself just said that. That's what "of all the things" *means*. You are about to talk about one of those things.

Comment: And there is no garden-pathiness here, intentional or not. There are no different competing parse trees. There is only one. You don't have to go back midpoint and look for another reading. There is only one reading. It's just that it's garbage, is all.

Comment: @RegDwigнt - So "Of all the things with purple stripes" would also include "law"???  "Of all the things" was qualified by "that money can't buy".  And you have to understand it as a riddle of sorts.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81124/discussion-between-regdwigt-and-hot-licks).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a (grammatically correct) double negative saying that something (law) is **not** a part of a group of things someone **can't** do...
-.-

So, if we flipped each one (you have to be mindful of maintaining semantic balance when you flip double negatives), we would end up with a sentence like:

> Of all the things money *can* buy, Law *is* one (of those things).

Or, more simply:

> Money can buy Law.

There are subtleties lost in such a direct of form expression, which is why the author chose to convey the message in their quasi-[litotic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Litotes) style.

Comment: Yeah no. Smoke and mirrors. Of course if we specifically go and reword the sentence to expressly mean what we actually want it to mean, then that rewording will be fine. The OP is not asking about "money can buy law". The OP is asking about "Of all the things money can't buy, Law isn't one" which is a completely different sentence that doesn't work anywhere the same as your rewording.

Comment: Yeah no: Yeah. "There are many things money can't buy: happiness, health, or good luck. Law isn't one of the things money cannot buy." That does, quite in fact, mean that Money Can Buy Law. Please propose another answer if you still disagree.

Comment: Um, where did you get that sentence from. That's not the sentence the OP is asking about. Why do you keep coming up with ever new sentences and answering questions about them. Nobody asked any questions about any of the sentences you are talking about.

Comment: But if you wished to reword the original sentence the way you did, the correct rewording would be "There are many things money can't buy: happiness, health, good luck, and law. But law isn't one of them. Although I only just said that it was."

Comment: I wished to reword the sentence in the manner in which I did, not in the manner which you present here. Please allow me to spell it out for you, if you have not had coffee yet:   Let there be a Set, S, of things that money cannot buy. Let ΣS represent the complete list (keyword: all) of items within S. Is "Law" a member of ΣS? If you answer, "No," then "Law isn't one [of the members of ΣS]." You present the phrase as nonsensical here because you assume that the statement isn't rhetorical, which it plainly is. I suppose you would have us do away with poetry, too.

Comment: +1 This is simple set theory.

Comment: So you wished to reword the sentence in the manner in which you did, not in the manner I present here. Correct. Likewise, I wished to reword the sentence in the manner in which I did, not in the manner which you present here. So. Um. Not sure what your point even is. That you're the only one allowed to reword? I didn't get the memo. Also no, I do not drink coffee, I stay away from drugs. It is precisely taking drugs that makes you mistake poorly written nonsense for poetry. And don't try to scare me with your pseudomaths, mate. I studied actual maths.

Comment: @RegDwigнt https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xzpndHtdl9A

Comment: Lol, what are you, twelve. Using this site at that age is against the ToS.

Answer (score 2):

It is grammatically correct, but nonsensical. Because of your use of the word *all*.

The construction "of all the *blahs*" signals to the reader that you are talking about a group of things, that are all *blahs*, from which you are about to single out one thing to compare it to all the other things in that group. You are about to explain how there's that one *blah* in that group that is different from all the other *blahs*.

> - Of all the primates, gorillas are the biggest.
> - Of all the palaces, the Louvre is my favorite.
> - Of all the things I can buy, law is the cheapest.

However, in your case the comparison you are trying to draw is that unlike every other element in the group, the element that you've singled out from the group actually isn't in the group at all. And that just doesn't make any sense. You are stating two things that directly contradict each other.

> - Of all the primates, crocodiles are not primates.
> - Of all my favorite palaces, David Hasselhoff isn't one.
> - Of all the apples in the basket, this apple is not in the basket.
> - Of all my closest friends, Osama bin Laden never was one.
> - Of all the gaming console manufacturers on the market, Reebok isn't one.
> - Of all the things I cannot buy, law is a thing I can buy.
> - Of all the stupid people on the Internet, you are not one.

This just doesn't work. At best it's rather comical, and indeed can be deliberately played for comedic effect. At worst it's utter nonsense.

If being funny is not your intention at all, which given the topic it might or might not be, then you need to reword.

**Edit** in response to comment: Yes, you can also expressly use this construction for surprise effect "to highlight the Purchasability of Law". Observe:

> - Of all the things money can't buy, law is the one money can buy most easily.
> - Of all the things money can't buy, law is the one with the lowest price tag.
> - Of all the things money can't buy, law is on sale most often.

Or any number of other alternatives. This actually has the punch you're after, and makes it clear that it's a point you're deliberately making. What you have right now is muddy and raises the question if it's deliberate at all, just a typo, or lack of sufficient command of the language.

Comment: The statement is clearly rhetorical and phrased in the manner which it is for effect. The interpretations you listed above, which are not consistent in their applications of your purported rules, go against the spirit of the utterance, which is to highlight the Purchasability of Law.

Comment: @tidbertum it is not clearly rhetorical, and the effect of this manner is "what the heck are you on about". You can make it clearly rhetorical, and you can phrase it in a manner for the desired effect. But there is nothing in the question or the statement that suggests that the effect is desired in the first place. You are imagining it.

Comment: @JasonBassford precisely right. That is exactly my point. If an item is not part of the group, you have no business saying it is. Which is exactly what the original sentence does. That is what "Of all the items in the group" *means*.

Comment: +1 I agree with the awkwardness of the original quote. Oddly enough, if the quote started with the word *out*: "Out of all the X, Y isn't one", it sounds fine.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to echo the answer provided by tidbertum but present it in a graphical fashion.

[image]

And to paraphrase the original sentence, with some styling and emphasis:

> Of [all the things that money can't buy], law is *not* one [of those things].

To further echo tidbertum and analyze the meaning of the sentence, because it's not one of those things that money *can't* buy, it is, logically, something that money *can* buy.

Comment: Is not the logical problem here to do with the word 'of'? It is that word that might mislead the reader into thinking that law is 'of' the set of all the things that money can't buy. And then we read that law is not a member of that set at all. An apparent contradiction! As so often in language, however, logic only gets one only  so far in understanding what is meant.

Comment: @JeremyC I agree that the wording might be slightly awkward, and I would likely rephrase it myself. (I can happily add a rephrased version that would avoid any confusion.) But doesn't the use of the comma and *isn't*, upon analysis of the complete sentence, preclude the opposite meaning from being obtained? In other words, isn't the contradiction only seemingly apparent (if taken that way) until further thought is given to it?

Comment: I did not say that I was misled by the sentence. I found its meaning perfectly clear, but I was trying to understand why one of our colleagues   was so adamant that the whole sentence was logical nonsense. Personally I found it a very effective bit of rhetoric (and I recall that traditionally rhetoric was taught as a separate subject from logic).

Comment: @JeremyC Ah, understood. I, too, believe that it's an effective use of rhetoric.

Comment: Yes, and I would add other things to the Law circle, like Coffee, Houses, Corrupt Politicians (an extension of the Law principle, in a sense), etc. :)

Comment: @JeremyC the funny thing is, I am not the one approaching this logically. I am approaching this purely from the language perspective. It's all the people who try to find a flaw in my argument who resort to logic and maths. Venn diagrams and sum symbols. But that's not how language works. At all. And look at them constantly rewording the sentence to sound better and make sense. And then going "look it sounds nice and makes sense". Well yes. Then how about you stop rewording it then, duh. I look at the actual sentence in my answer. And I do not use maths. This is a language site.